# What does 'input:-webkit-autofill' select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

JavaScript code (with jQuery)

```
$('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a custom WebKit selector.

In supporting browsers, jQuery will call the native [`querySelectorAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll).
Thus method will recognize browser-specific selectors.

Comment: feed what to querySelectorAll, input:-auto-fill or just -auto-fill?

Comment: @lovespring: The entire selector.  Search the jQuery source for `querySelectorAll` to see how it works.